# Rails: How to create has_many through relationships via the ids in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

I have three models: `Customer`, `Branch` and `CustomerBranch`

In Customer model:

```
has_many :customer_branches, inverse_of: :customer
has_many :branches, through: :customer_branches
```

In Branch model:

```
has_many :customer_branches, inverse_of: :branch, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
has_many :customers, through: :customer_branches
```

In CustomerBranch model:

```
belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :customer_branches
belongs_to :branch, inverse_of: :customer_branches
```

It's an api only application and i'll be getting an array of branch ids. Now i want to assign/remove branches from the customer based on ids received.

I have a solution to handle this but i don't think it's the best possible way. Here's my current solution:

```
attr_accessor :branches_ids
after_save :assign_branches

def assign_branches
  return if self.branches_ids.nil?
  old_branch_ids = self.branch_ids

  remove_branch_ids = old_branch_ids - self.branches_ids

  self.customer_branches.where(id: remove_branch_ids).delete_all if remove_branch_ids.present?

  self.branches << Branch.where(id: self.branches_ids)
end
```

Is there any better way to handle this? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: That's not how this works in Rails... check out saving related models: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I am aware of nested attributes but reluctant to use them as there is no field other than ids.

Comment: In that case... you can just use the build in `association` method in the form. The Customer model should only be dealing with things about the customer, not involved when it comes to Branches. That;s the concept of single responsibility.

Comment: In case you use Simple Form: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

Comment: It's an api only application. I'll be getting an array of ids.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies the question! Still, I don't think this belongs in the Customer model though. You could still create the same structure and save everything in one go. Just have a look in the object that normally would be provided by the form. Saving that would just be enough. I think the param would be something like `branches_ids: [1,2,3]`

Comment: yeah that's why i have added attr_accessor :branches_ids. So basically client will be sending this param. Now i need to create/remove associations and that i am doing in the callback. But again the issue is i think there must be some better way. I must not be the only one facing this dilemma. I googled but no satisfactory results.

Comment: See my answer... you just assign the array of IDs directly on the customer. It even doesn't have to be created yet. Rails will first create the user and then the branches in the same transaction.

Comment: Ok..let me check

Comment: no need to define `attr_accessor :branches_ids`, this is already implied as `branches_ids` is already an instance method.

Comment: Yeah man..this seems to be working. I'll test this a bit more and then accept the answer. Thanks !!

Comment: Yeah, Rails is quite versatile! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, to answer the question. You can just set the IDs directly on the customer:

```
customer = Customer.find(1)
customer.branches_ids = [1,2,3]
```

Rails will handle all the additions and deletions.

Also works with new Customers:

```
customer = Customer.new
customer.name = "blabla"
customer.branches_ids = [1,2,3]
customer.save
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same concern when building a **Rails application** on **Ubuntu 20.04**

The models and controllers were namespaced into a module called `Userbase`:

**User model**

```
module Userbase
  class User < ApplicationRecord

    # Allow a user to have multiple permissions
    has_many :user_permissions, class_name: Userbase::UserPermission, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :permissions, through: :user_permissions

    # Allow a user to have multiple roles
    has_many :user_roles, class_name: Userbase::UserRole, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
  end
end
```

**Role model**

```
module Userbase
  class Role < ApplicationRecord

    # Allow a role to have multiple users
    has_many :user_roles, class_name: Userbase::UserRole, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :users, through: :user_roles

    # Allow a role to have multiple permissions
    has_many :role_permissions, class_name: Userbase::Role, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :permissions, through: :role_permissions
  end
end
```

**Permission Model**

```
module Userbase
  class Permission < ApplicationRecord

    # Allow a permission to have multiple users
    has_many :user_permissions, class_name: Userbase::UserPermission, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :users, through: :user_permissions

    # Allow a permission to have multiple roles
    has_many :role_permissions, class_name: Userbase::Role, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :roles, through: :role_permissions
  end
end
```

**Role Permission Model**

```
module Userbase
  class RolePermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :role, class_name: Userbase::Role
    belongs_to :permission, class_name: Userbase::Permission
  end
end
```

**User Permission Model**

```
module Userbase
  class UserPermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, class_name: Userbase::User
    belongs_to :permission, class_name: Userbase::Permission
  end
end
```

**User Role Model**

```
module Userbase
  class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, class_name: Userbase::User
    belongs_to :role, class_name: Userbase::Role
  end
end
```

**Here's how I did it**:

I added the `role_ids: []`, `permission_ids: []`, and `user_ids: []` in the allowed parameters for the corresponding controllers:

**Role Controller**

```
module Userbase
  module Api
    module V1
      class RolesController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_role, only: %i[show update destroy]
        .
        .
        .
        private

        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_role
          @role = Userbase::Role.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
        def role_params
          params.require(:role).permit(:name, :description, user_ids: [], permission_ids: [] )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**User Controller**

```
module Userbase
  module Api
    module V1
      class UsersController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_user, only: %i[show update destroy]
        .
        .
        .
        private

        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_user
          @role = Userbase::User.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
        def role_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:name, :description, role_ids: [], permission_ids: [] )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Permission Controller**

```
module Userbase
  module Api
    module V1
      class PermissionsController < ApplicationController
        before_action :set_permission, only: %i[show update destroy]
        .
        .
        .
        private

        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_permission
          @role = Userbase::Permission.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
        def role_params
          params.require(:permission).permit(:name, :description, role_ids: [], user_ids: [] )
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So I can now **create permissions** using:

```
{
    "permission": {
        "name": "create_school",
        "description": "This is the permission to create schools"
    }
}
```

We can also **create roles** using:

```
{
    "role": {
        "name": "Student",
        "description": "This is the role for students",
        "permission_ids": [1,2]
    }
}
```

We can also **create users** using:

```
{
    "user": {
        "first_name": "Kelvin",
        "middle_name": "Daniel",
        "last_name": "Wale",
        "email": "kelvin-wale@gmail.com",
        "password": "123456",
        "password_confirmation": "123456",
        "username": "kelvin-wale",
        "role_ids": [1],
        "permission_ids": [1,2]
    }
}
```

I also wanted to create a default role each time a user is created, so I added the following method and `before_save` callback to the user model:

**User model**

```
module Userbase
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    before_save :assign_default_role

    # Allow a user to have multiple permissions
    has_many :user_permissions, class_name: Userbase::UserPermission, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :permissions, through: :user_permissions

    # Allow a user to have multiple roles
    has_many :user_roles, class_name: Userbase::UserRole, dependent: :nullify
    has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
  end

  # Assign the student role by default to users
  def assign_default_role
    role = Userbase::Role.find_by(name: 'Student')
    self.role_ids = role.id
  end
end
```

**Note**: The role should be created first or be seeded already into the database using:

```
Userbase::Role.delete_all

# Default role
puts 'Creating default role'
Userbase::Role.create([{ name: 'Student',
                         description: 'This is the role for students',
                         permission_ids: [1, 2] }])
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in your controller:

```
def assign_branches
  customer = Customer.find(params[:id]) // however you gonna get custome whom we gonna assign branches
  customer.branches = Branch.where(id: params[:branch_ids]) //however way you want to get ids
end
```

The collection= method makes the collection contain only the supplied objects, by adding and deleting as appropriate. The changes are persisted to the database.For more about association, you can go through: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference